# How to make IntelliJ prompt me for command line arguments

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea, ide

In Eclipse, you can provide the program argument `${string_prompt}` in your run configuration to have it prompt for the command line arguments.

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting from versions 2018.3 and 2019.1, IntelliJ now supports macros in Run configurations. You can use `$Prompt$` anywhere in the VM Options, Program arguments, etc. fields, and it will behave just like `${string_prompt}` in Eclipse -- it will prompt you for parameters when the configuration is run.

Answer (score 23):

## Edit:

This may be a bug in IDEA, the solution that I first posted (you can see it below) causes Intellij to hang after entering parameter.

I couldn't come up with a solution to this, but here's a little trick: you can scroll to the very bottom of Run/Debug configuration screen and in "Before launch" section check a checkbox saying "Show this page".

From now on you'll be **automatically shown configuration screen** when you choose to Run/Debug your application and there you can enter any parameters you want... It's not that comfortable, but at least *a little bit* more automatized.

## Previous answer:

This is a bit more complicated with Intellij:

- go to `Settings -> External Tools -> Add (green plus)`
- in `Parameters` line click `Insert macro -> Prompt` (you can simply type in `$Prompt$` as well)
- save settings
- go to `Run -> Edit Configurations...`
- in `Before Launch` section choose `Run External Tool` and select tool that you've created

That should suffice (works in IDEA 12.1.6).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Michal, tried this and it seems like the run just hangs/dies and I can't re-run unless I re-open intelliJ. In the config for the external tool, is there anything else you set other than the `$Prompt$` param? Did you leave the `Program` and `Working Directory` fields blank?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, busy days. You're right - I saw it prompting for parameter and assumed it works... please see my edited answer, this is all I could think of for now.

Comment: This works only for a single `$Prompt$`. Do you know if it's possible to have multiple prompts and how? Thanks

Comment: @maricn Maybe a bit late, but try: `$Prompt$ $Prompt$`, this gets a bit annoying when you need a lot of arguments or an unknown amount of argument, perhaps then create a fallback to split the first argument based on spaces

Answer (score 3):

Based on using Intellij IDEA 2020.3, we can set the configuration to prompt for program arguments at the program arguments field

[image: Right click the program and then choose menu More Run/Debug > Modify Run Configuration]

[image: Look for the Program arguments text field]

[image: Type $Prompt$ at the Program arguments text field and then click OK]