# Automation for terminal commands input in IntelliJ IDEA-family IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

If frequently input similar commands in IDE's terminal, can I automate it somehow?

For example, I use **PhpStorm** and frequently create MVC-controller in Laravel framework by console command like `php artisan make:controller CotrollerName`. The ideal that I want:

1. Some simple action like shortcut pressing
2. Modal window "Please, input controller name".
3. Pressing **Enter**

Then IDE will automatically input `php artisan make:controller InputtedCotrollerName` to console and run it.

What is currently possible instead of this?

Comment: There is a Laravel plugin for PhpStorm which supports this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm#LaravelDevelopmentusingPhpStorm-CommandLineToolSupportforArtisanandComposer

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702509/965834) may help. In short, you can create an external tool instance and have it prompt for parameters when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicate things, simple alias would be better for this, like:

```
alias pamc='php artisan make:controller '
```

which then you can use in PHPStrorm by opening embedded terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> by default) and typing `pamc ControllerName`

Answer (score 0):

As seems like you use Laravel you could consider using the Laravel plugin for PhpStorm. Which should provide most of the functionality you want, and a bit more.

Or

you can do what [streetturtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51635051/6439460) suggested and create alias. They can save lots of writing time.